# How to align a fixed ion-segment over ion-grid

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have the following ionic code:

```css
ion-segment-button{
     --indicator-box-shadow: transparent!important;
     border-radius: 0.5rem !important;
     margin: 0;
     --background:white;
     --color:#2d2e87;
     --background-checked: #3880ff !important;
     --color-checked: white;
     --indicator-color : transparent!important; /* this solution */
}
```

```html
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-segment (ionChange)='onFilterUpdate($event)' value='all' slot="fixed">
    <ion-segment-button value='all'>All places</ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value='bookable'>Bookable places</ion-segment-button>
  </ion-segment>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size='12' size-sm='8' offset-sm='2' text-center>
        <ion-card>
          <ion-card-header>
            <ion-card-title>{{loadedPlaces[0].title}}</ion-card-title>
            <ion-card-subtitle>{{loadedPlaces[0].price | currency}}/Night</ion-card-subtitle>
          </ion-card-header>
          
...
```

The ion-segment is getting fixed at the top but it is flowing over ion-grid like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGD7T.png)

Can someone suggest how to fix this so that the segment and grid are in their right places?

Answer (score 0):

use `ion-grid` to keep them on top of each other and not not over flow

here is a example code

```
<ion-grid>
 <ion-row>
 <ion-segment (ionChange)='onFilterUpdate($event)' value='all' slot="fixed">
    <ion-segment-button value='all'>All places</ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value='bookable'>Bookable places</ion-segment-button>
  </ion-segment>
 </ion-row>
 <ion-row>
   <ion-col size='12' size-sm='8' offset-sm='2' text-center>
      <ion-card>
        <ion-card-header>
          <ion-card-title>
             {{loadedPlaces[0].title}}
          </ion-card-title>
          <ion-card-subtitle>
              {{loadedPlaces[0].price | currency}}/Night
          </ion-card-subtitle>
        </ion-card-header>
     <ion-card>
    </ion-col>
 </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

This will create 2 rows on top of each other while segments occupy first row and expand to fill the whole row the 2nd row can have a col of size 8 to host you card

Comment: Don't know why but my segment has disappeared from the UI after I added it to the grid itself. Just to let you know, I have a list of items added to rows after this code. So I'm asking for the first row(segment) to be floating on the top when I scroll down.

Comment: So you want the Segment to be fixed on top and then have a list of items which shall scroll down maybe/probably  list of infinite items

Answer (score 0):

You should add margin-top for Ion-Grid. Ideally, the pixel for margin-top will be the height of ion-segment. Also set white background to ion-segment.
I don't know how you style in Angular, but in React, if the height of the IonSegment is 48px, the code would be

```
<IonContent>
  <IonSegment slot="fixed style={{background:'white'}}>
  <IonSegment/>
  <IonGrid style={{marginTop:'48px'}}></IonGrid>
</IonContent>
```